# Uploading files to site / datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, upload

I'm trying to make a little site for few people. Basically what i'm looking for is that users can register to this site, log on and upload files. I want the files to upload to a new folder that is named after the uID for example.

User Tommy registers and get user id 1234.
Then his upload folder will be 
http://www.site.com/users/1234/upload/

He is the only one that has access to this data and can delete them.

Another way would be storing this info in the sql. I'm using MS SQL 2008. Can i save the upload attachments right in the datatable ? or should i have one account that has full rights that will make the folders for the users and save the direct link in the database ?

I'm going for a little, very so light version of dropbox.com but only in a browser form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And if you go though folder route,

System.IO FileInfo and DirectoryInfo will give you all the info you need about the contents of a folder, and the files within it.

And dont forget Server.MapPath() :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [FILESTREAM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc949109.aspx) in SQL Server 2008, which is designed to efficiently store unstructured data.

BOL: [FILESTREAM Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993.aspx)